# 'Bad file descriptor' error from URL session data task on Apple Watch?

Tags: runtime-error, watchos, urlsession

I'm working on an independent watchOS app and I'm testing on the Apple Watch Ultra simulator as well as a couple of real Apple Watch Ultra devices (both have active cellular data service (AT&T), are within 3 feet of their paired iPhones and connected to WiFi, as well).

My app registers with APNs to receive remote notifications.  When I receive the token (in `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications(withDeviceToken:)`), I create a URLSession data task to send it to the server that will generate and send the notifications.
This code works 100% of the time on the Apple Watch Ultra simulator but on a real Apple Watch Ultra, about 2/3 of the time, I get the following error message in the Xcode debug console:

```
2023-05-12 08:32:30.779560-0400 Watch App Prototype[569:586139] PDTask <5110B87C-28D7-48C9-9C68-121C7728FF68>.<2> finished with error [9] Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=9 "Bad file descriptor" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=9, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataPDTask <5110B87C-28D7-48C9-9C68-121C7728FF68>.<2>",
    "LocalDataTask <5110B87C-28D7-48C9-9C68-121C7728FF68>.<2>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataPDTask <5110B87C-28D7-48C9-9C68-121C7728FF68>.<2>}
2023-05-12 08:32:30.780401-0400 Watch App Prototype[569:586139] Task <5110B87C-28D7-48C9-9C68-121C7728FF68>.<2> finished with error [9] Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=9 "Bad file descriptor" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=9, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <5110B87C-28D7-48C9-9C68-121C7728FF68>.<2>",
    "LocalDataPDTask <5110B87C-28D7-48C9-9C68-121C7728FF68>.<2>",
    "LocalDataTask <5110B87C-28D7-48C9-9C68-121C7728FF68>.<2>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <5110B87C-28D7-48C9-9C68-121C7728FF68>.<2>}
The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad file descriptor
```

I ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027484/trying-to-make-network-requests-from-a-standalone-apple-watch-app) post which describes what appears to be the same/similar problem and that person's code is obviously different than mine so I'm not sure that it's a code issue.  When this error occurs, the URL request is definitely not completing.

For what it's worth, here's the code that I'm using to send the URL request:

```
func perform(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) async throws -> Data {
    let (data, response) = try await urlSession.data(for: urlRequest)
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        throw NetworkError.serverSideError(response: nil)
    }        
    guard (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
        throw NetworkError.serverSideError(response: httpResponse)
    }
    return data
}
```

By the way, urlSession in the above code is the URLSession shared singleton. Has anyone else ever run into this error message?